# Wordpress can't find IXR_Client

Tags: page-template, xml-rpc

Trying:

```
$client = new IXR_Client('http://othersite.com/xmlrpc.php');
```

I get the error

**Fatal error:** Class 'IXR_Client' not found in footer.php

I can see the class in *wp-includes/class-IXR.php*, and I've checked that the path to this file is correct in *wp-includes/functions.php* as per [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/publishing-post-gives-me-error-message?replies=5) discussion.

Am I missing something needed to use this class in my custom theme's footer?

Comment: Rob, give the answer an up-vote out of courtesy, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean class-IRC.php or class-IXR.php?

Just include the files before you call `IXR_Client`. I use such code to call IXR_CLIENT and it worked on my site:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php' );

$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT( 'http://othersite.com/xmlrpc.php' );
```

Comment: Yes, meant _class-IXR.php_; works great!